# UPDATE inventory table after sale transaction

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update QTY in Inventory table after sale transaction based on product_id

Inventory table has
Product_id
QTY_onhand

Sale table has
sale_id
product_id
QTY_sold

product table has
product_id
product_name

if the customer purchase 2 apples I need to update the inventory table by subtracting 2 from QTY_onhand based on Apple ID in product table

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.  Have you tried something yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Look for triggers .

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow has a rule that not allow homework problem :)

Comment: Maybe it is not a rule but there are some good practices. Doing someone's homework is not good practice for both sides.

Comment: I don't need any one to do it for me. I just need some suggestions or idea that can help me to do it by my self :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UPDATE Inventory SET QTY_onhand = QTY_onhand - A.QTY_sold
FROM 
(
   SELECT Sale.QTY_sold, Sale.product_id FROM Sale
   WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM product WHERE product_name = 'apples' AND      
   product.product_id = Sale.product_id)
)A
WHERE Inventory.product_id = A.product_id
```

Comment: What is A mean?

Comment: A is alias name for sub query

Comment: You can't use an UPDATE FROM statement in oracle.  For similar functionality you need to use the MERGE statement instead or a correlated subquery on the right hand side of the set statement.  Additionally the OP won't want to run this statement more than once or they'll eventually loose all their apples.